# 3D Convolution with Intel MKL

Tags: c++, c, 3d, convolution, intel-mkl

I have written a `C/C++` code which uses Intel MKL to compute the 3D convolution of an array which has *about* `300×200×200` elements. I want to apply a kernel which is either `3×3×3` or `5×5×5`. Both the 3D input array and the kernel have real values.

This 3D array is stored as a 1D array of type `double` in a columnwise fashion. Similarly the kernel is of type `double` and is saved columnwise. For example,

```
for( int k = 0; k < nk; k++ ) // Loop through the height.
    for( int j = 0; j < nj; j++ ) // Loop through the rows.
        for( int i = 0; i < ni; i++ ) // Loop through the columns.
        {
            ijk = i + ni * j + ni * nj * k;
            my3Darray[ ijk ] = 1.0;
        }
```

For the computation of convolution, I want to perform `not-in-place` FFT on the input array and the kernel and prevent them from getting modified (I need to use them later in my code) and then do the backward computation `in-place`.

When I compare the result obtained from my code with the one obtained by `MATLAB` they are very different. Could someone kindly help me fix the issue? What is missing in my code?

Here is the `MATLAB` code I used:

```
a = ones( 10, 10, 10 );
kernel = ones( 3, 3, 3 );
aconvolved = convn( a, kernel, 'same' );
```

Here is my `C/C++` code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "mkl.h"

void Conv3D(
    double *in, double *ker, double *out,
    int nRows, int nCols, int nHeights)
{

    int NI = nRows;
    int NJ = nCols;
    int NK = nHeights;

    double *in_fft  = new double [NI*NJ*NK];
    double *ker_fft = new double [NI*NJ*NK];

    DFTI_DESCRIPTOR_HANDLE fft_desc = 0;
    MKL_LONG sizes[]   = { NK, NJ, NI };
    MKL_LONG strides[] = { 0, NJ*NI, NI, 1 };

    DftiCreateDescriptor( &fft_desc, DFTI_DOUBLE, DFTI_REAL, 3, sizes     );
    DftiSetValue        (  fft_desc, DFTI_PLACEMENT     , DFTI_NOT_INPLACE);   // Out-of-place computation.
    DftiSetValue        (  fft_desc, DFTI_INPUT_STRIDES , strides         );
    DftiSetValue        (  fft_desc, DFTI_OUTPUT_STRIDES, strides         );
    DftiSetValue        (  fft_desc, DFTI_BACKWARD_SCALE, 1/NI/NJ/NK      );
    DftiCommitDescriptor(  fft_desc );

    DftiComputeForward  (  fft_desc, in , in_fft  );
    DftiComputeForward  (  fft_desc, ker, ker_fft );

    for (long long i = 0; i < (long long)NI*NJ*NK; ++i )
        out[i] = in_fft[i]*ker_fft[i];

    // In-place computation.
    DftiSetValue        (  fft_desc, DFTI_PLACEMENT, DFTI_INPLACE );
    DftiCommitDescriptor(  fft_desc      );
    DftiComputeBackward (  fft_desc, out );

    DftiFreeDescriptor  ( &fft_desc );

    delete[] in_fft;
    delete[] ker_fft;

}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int n = 10;
    int nkernel = 3;

    double *a          = new double [n*n*n]; // This array is real.
    double *aconvolved = new double [n*n*n]; // The convolved array is also real.
    double *kernel     = new double [nkernel*nkernel*nkernel]; // kernel is real.

    // Fill the array with some 'real' numbers.
    for( int i = 0; i < n*n*n; i++ )
        a[ i ] = 1.0;

    // Fill the kernel with some 'real' numbers.
    for( int i = 0; i < nkernel*nkernel*nkernel; i++ )
        kernel[ i ] = 1.0;

    // Calculate the convolution.
    Conv3D( a, kernel, aconvolved, n, n, n );

    printf("Convolved:\n");
    for( int i = 0; i < n*n*n; i++ )
        printf( "%15.8f\n", aconvolved[i] );

    delete[] a;
    delete[] kernel;
    delete[] aconvolved;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I like your question but I can't help. However, it would probably help others help you if you gave them the expected result alongside your results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't reverse the FFT with real-valued frequency data (just the magnitude).  A forward FFT needs to output complex data.  This is done by setting the [`DFTI_FORWARD_DOMAIN` setting](https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/470830#7AD8D4C9-82B8-427E-8290-741958198697) to `DFTI_COMPLEX`.

```
DftiCreateDescriptor( &fft_desc, DFTI_DOUBLE, DFTI_COMPLEX, 3, sizes     );
```

Doing this implicitly sets the backward domain to complex too.

You will also need a complex data type.  Probably something like,

```
MKL_Complex16* in_fft  = new MKL_Complex16[NI*NJ*NK];
```

This means you will have to multiply both the real and imaginary parts:

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < (size_t)NI*NJ*NK; ++i) {
    out_fft[i].real = in_fft[i].real * ker_fft[i].real;
    out_fft[i].imag = in_fft[i].imag * ker_fft[i].imag;
}
```

The output of the inverse FFT is also complex, and assuming your input data is real, you can just grab the `.real` component and that is your result.  This means you'll need a temporary complex output array (say, `out_fft` as above).

Also note that to avoid artifacts, you want the size of your fft to be (at least) M+N-1 on each dimension.  Generally you would choose the next highest power of two for speed.

I strongly suggest you implement it in MATLAB first, using FFTs.  There are many such implementations available ([example](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/24504-fft-based-convolution)), but I would start from the basics and make a simple function on your own.